# How to Make Players Deal More Damage at Night?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've looked all over the internet and I couldn't find anything. I was wondering if there was a way that at night/day(preferrably night) if somehow a player will do more damage to mobs and players with commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setup a scoreboard with the current time:
`scoreboard objectives add currentTime dummy`

In a tick function or repeating command block put:
`execute store result score @a currentTime run time query daytime`

Under the above line in your tick function or in a different repeating command block:
`execute as @a if score @s currentTime matches 13183..22800 run effect give @s minecraft:strength 1 0`

Basically, when the time is night it will give every player strength 1, which will make them hit harder. You can change the level of strength from 0 to whatever you want depending on what damage boost you want.

Answer (score 1):

You could always have an inverted daylight sensor that powers a repeating command block that requires redstone. I’m it have the command /effect @a strength 9999 1 (for strength 1). Then have a normal daylight sensor that has a repeating command block that requires redstone. Then the command would be /effect @a clear. If you get too far it will stop working, but you could always build more. (The commands I wrote are for pocket edition, I don’t know them for java edition).

Comment: What do you mean with "not very effective"? This solution seems to be fine to me. I'd suggest adding the command that should be used to the answer, and to add what kind of command block to use. In this case probably something like `effect give @a minecraft:strength 1 1` in a repeating command block that requires redstone.

Comment: I edited my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: You really don't want the effect to last for 9999 seconds though... The rest is ok and may only need a bit of formatting for readability.

Comment: Actually after looking looking a bit more closely, the answer was probably better before the edit, if you use the command `effect give @a minecraft:strength 1 1` in the command block, then the effect would automatically stop one second after the night ends, you wouldn't need to clear it anymore. This command works in the java edition, too.

Comment: That is true. That worked better